# Allowing either growl or terminal notifier for guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard, gemfile

Ok currently I can get either the [Growl](https://rubygems.org/gems/growl) or [Terminal Notifier](https://github.com/Springest/terminal-notifier-guard) to work with Guard. Whichever one I place in my `Gemfile` and run `bundle` with then works.

I need to have some place other than the `Gemfile` to choose which one to use. I'm working on a project with multiple developers, and most use Growl. I prefer Terminal Notifier.

I don't want to make the changes in the `Gemfile` because that's in version control.

I can't figure out a way to move this into the `Guardfile`. Is the next best thing to just do a straight include in the Gemfile and have that be separated out where each developer can edit their `.extra-gems` file or something? That seems messy.

Comment: Is the Gemfile.lock also shared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do not configure your notifications, then Guard tries to auto-detect as much notification features as possible. You can make use of the [notification](https://github.com/guard/guard#notification) method to configure the notifications to your needs. Guard also knows [shared configurations](https://github.com/guard/guard#shared-configurations), which allows you to have your very own configuration in your home directory.

You can now set your personal notification settings in `~/.guard.rb`:

`notification :terminal_title`

This will disable the auto-detection, enabling only the terminal title notification.